# how to access current_user in activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to access current_user in activeadmin rails?

like devise current_user, but i'dont know how to call current_user in active_admin rails?

thanks before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `current_admin_user`. because the ActiveAdmin user model is called 'AdminUser' by default.

Comment: i get error like this "*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user' for #<ActiveAdmin::Namespace:0xc0d7224>", in my route :   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

Comment: can you show your code (with current_active_admin method)?

Comment: article.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  current_admin_user
end

i'm not sure how to access current_admin_user

Comment: fix my problem, you right with current_admin_user... thank you